# Using IDEA, how to debug web app that is deployed to local tomcat?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Using IDEA, how to debug web app that is deployed to local tomcat?

Answer (score 3):

Edit your run/debug configurations and add a "remote" configuration. Instructions contained in that very dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the remote configuration instruction is necessary.  Just add breakpoints to your Java classes or JSPs and run in debug mode.  If Tomcat is local to your machine, that's all you need to do.

Comment: I did that, it didn't seem to work i.e. it rendered the view page w/o stopping at the break point, i'll give it a go tonight hopefully.